# Regarding SOAP clients backward compatibility for service name change

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, wsdl

One of a internal web service provider provides the SOAP RPC API to connect to their system. Recently they changed their service name that gets reflected from their wsdl.

For e.g 
if the service was previously "MyService", it has been changed to "MyService1" but the address location remains the same.

```
<wsdl:service name="MyService">
<wsdl:port binding="tns:MyServiceSoapBinding" name="APIImplPort">
<soap:address location="http://10.64.16.141:8080/cms/APIImpl"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>


<wsdl:service name="MyService1">
<wsdl:port binding="tns:MyService1SoapBinding" name="APIImplPort">
<soap:address location="http://10.64.16.141:8080/cms/APIImpl"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Will it require to change the existing clients or will they work without any change?

Specifically, I am using java along with spring JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean to connect to the above web service. I can see that I have to change the service name to make it work but I am not sure whether this is due to the underlying mechanism(spring JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean) that I have to change the service name to make it work or otherwise that can work with any other technology without any change(for e.g .NET).

Comment: The service name has changed thus MyService has been replaced. Code will not work out of the box you will need to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In nutshell, if you are using service name on your client side(This happens when you want to use some framework in your technology to send the SOAP packets to the server), backward compatibility will not work. This is due to the fact that SOAP xml packet doesn't refers the service name, it refers the name space, operation etc..
If you are sending SOAP xml packets directly, the service name change will not make any impact in any technology.

Further, in .Net technology implementation it gets handled by technology itself, but in java it breaks the backward compatibility because we have to specify the service name with most of the techniques(frameworks) to send the SOAP packet to the server. Probably backward compatibility breaks in other technologies also.

**Java**: I got the below errors when I haven’t changed the service name:-
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: {xx/}MyService is not a valid service. Valid services are: {xx/}MyService1

I thought that this might be due to my underlying spring framework of my Java Technology but then I tried very raw implementation(http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/) and I can see that the service name has to be specified in order to send the SOAP packet to server.

**.Net** the application works in .Net without any service name change(If I don't need the updated operations of Changed service MyService1) based on assumption that the underlying mechanism handles the service change from the referenced wsdl.